# How to stop ggplot2 connecting all points when plotting ellipses?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've got a really annoying problem plotting ellipses with ggplot2 and I wonder if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong? All the points link up!

I usually do this using the standard plot() and ordiellipse() but been trying to use ggplot for prettiness, but this happens. I will admit to gleaning the 'for loop' code from the internets, but I can't see an error in it.

This is what I get:
[image: Conjoined NMDS points]

I'm doing this:

```
## The NMDS coords have been pre-calculated, and the file looks like this:
     NMDS1 NMDS2 Site Species
Sample.1 -0.390516864 -0.227890627 1 Lr
Sample.2 -0.433137678 -0.221231786 1 Al
Sample.3 -0.16384753 0.243258745 1 Lt
Sample4 -0.444995027 -0.174555074 1 Ac
Sample.5 -0.569417948 -0.223738264 2 Lr
Sample.6 -0.543744761 -0.234924777 2 Lt
.......etc

# Code
all <-read.table("/Users/Dan/Downloads/all.txt", header=TRUE)
df_ell <- data.frame(x=all$NMDS1, y=all$NMDS2, group=all$Species)

for(g in levels(all$Species)){
     df_ell <- rbind(df_ell, cbind(as.data.frame(with(all[all$Species==g,], ellipse(cor(NMDS1, NMDS2), scale=c(sd(NMDS1),sd(NMDS2)), 
     centre=c(mean(NMDS1),mean(NMDS2))))),group=g))}

# Generate plot
p <- ggplot(all, aes(NMDS1, NMDS2))

# plot it
p + geom_point(size = 4, alpha=.8, aes(colour = factor(Species), shape = factor(Site))) + geom_path(data=df_ell, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=group), size=1, linetype=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop that creates `df_ell`, `df_ell` should start empty, not as a copy of the data in `all` as otherwise you add the data in `all` to each ellipse, which is why they are shown as part of the path.

Comment: Thank you! It is so obvious when you point it out! I can't believe I didn't see it.Much appreciated.